# validating home address in jquery or javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate home address that is street address. But it returns false everytime. Here is my code

```
validateAddress: function (val) {
            console.log('val: ' + val);
            var streetregex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] ?([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]|[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] )*[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]$/;
            if ( streetregex.test(val) ) {
                console.log('true');
            } else {
                console.log('false');
            }

        }
```

val has street address in this format `street name streetnumber, city`.

How can I fix it so it correctly validates my address?

**Update**

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cEnS2/)

if you give address like this `Street name 18, Helsinki`. It returns false whereas I want it to return true for these sort of addresses.

Comment: Could you probably point us to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Street name only appears to be one character..

Comment: The question is way too vaguely phrased, given the complexity of real-life addresses. For example, your format (not the regexp) won't accept "123 Main St., New York".

Comment: @al0neevenings And what about the data you're using to test it..?

Comment: I've updated [my fiddle with your Helsinki example](http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/fxxTK/3/)

Comment: What data are you asking about?

Comment: You're testing the regex **against something**, what is that something?

Comment: That is `Street name 18, Helsinki`. @DanDascalescu answer works for me for this sort of data.

Comment: I don't think you can validate even your minimal (and unusual) street address requirements with any certainty using only a regular expression, though you might use one for tokenisation. You probably need to parse the parts manually, e.g. how will you cope with an address of "7th Avenue 24a, 1770"? Yes "1770" is a place name.

Comment: I only need addresses in this format `Street name 18, Helsinki`. The rest of them must be rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regexp will do what you ask for, but I doubt it's useful for any real-life application:

```
var regexp = /^[\w\s.-]+\d+,\s*[\w\s.-]+$/;
console.log(regexp.test('Main St. 123, New York'));
console.log(regexp.test('123 Wall St., New York'));
```

​
Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/fxxTK/5/

The way it works is:

```
match a sequence of alphanumeric characters, spaces, period or dash, e.g. "Abel-Johnson St."
followed by a number
followed by a comma
followed by another sequence of alphanumeric characters, spaces, period or dash (e.g. "St. Mary-Helen")
```

This is very frail, however, and you should probably simply not attempt to validate street addresses.

Comment: +1, for actually specifying they need to match more than one character.  Although it could do with an explanation for why what is needed.

Comment: Correct, it's intended to fail, per OP's format: "street name street number, city" (not "street number street name, city".

Comment: @Daedalus—it doesn't really matter since the OP's requirements are almost impossible to meet. e.g. Glen Retreat Road 24-26/415, New York and many others.

Comment: +1 for "and you should probably simply not attempt to validate street addresses" are far from regular and the web is international. I don't know how many times I've had to write a bogus address because someone (for the billionth time) thought that USA == world was a correct assertion